# Linear partitioning using recursivity

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, sum, partitioning

I know that there are similar questions, but I can`t modify my code using them.

Imagine that we have some works to do whith this costs of times n=[8,6,7,2,1,4], and 3 workers to do them. So if we want to calculate the best way to make the partition we can evaluate all the options (which is what I want to do with the recursive funcion). These would be all the options:

```
1- 1st worker:[8]; 2nd worker:[6]; 3rd worker:[7,2,1,4] --> Cost=max(8, 6 , 7+2+1+4=14)=14
2- 1:[8]; 2:[6,7]; 3:[2,1,4] --> Cost=max(8,13,7)=13 <------ best
3- 1:[8,6]; 2:[7]; 3:[2,1,4] --> Cost=max(14,7,7)=14 
4- 1:[8]; 2:[6,7,2]; 3:[1,4] --> Cost=max(8,15,5)=15 
5- 1:[8,6]; 2:[7,2]; 3:[1,4] --> Cost=max(14,9,5)=14 
6- 1:[8,6,7]; 2:[2]; 3:[1,4] --> Cost=max(21,2,5)=21 
7- 1:[8]; 2:[6,7,2,1]; 3:[4] --> Cost=max(8,16,4)=16 
8- 1:[8,6]; 2:[7,2,1]; 3:[4] --> Cost=max(14,10,4)=14 
9- 1:[8,6,7]; 2:[2,1]; 3:[4] --> Cost=max(21,3,4)=21 
10- 1:[8,6,7,2]; 2:[1]; 3:[4] --> Cost=max(23,1,4)=23
```

It is clear that 8 / 6,7 / 2,1,4 is the best option to do it as it is the minimum sum of the maximum of pratitions. I want to design a code in Pyhton which calculate the best partition with any numbers of tasks and anyy number of workers.

I have started my code this way:

```
def ib(n,j): #n:list with times,j:number of workers
    if j==1:
        return sum(n) #if we have just 1 worker 
    else:
        for i in range(j-1,len(n)+1): #to explore all the options of the right 
            left=ib(n[0:i],j-1)
            right=sum(n[i:len(n)])
            if right>left:
                left=right
ib([8,6,7,2,1,4],3)
```

My idea is to find the sum of the times of the last worker and apply the function again to the left with one worker less until I have just 1 worker. I have an error because the fuction gets out of the for and I get a None for the left side. I don't know how to correct this.

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't see a return statement in the `else` side of your if.

Comment: Surely 8,1 / 7,2 / 6,4 (max: 10) is the optimal solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are too many flaws to fix just a detail or two in your code; I'd be doing your homework for you.  However, here are some basic items to start you on your way.

You get **None** for the result because you neglected to **return** anything from the main branch of your function, the **else** clause.  The default value for a function is **None**.

Also, your logic fails to retain the solution; it finds only the local best.  As you recur back up the call stack, you need to form the various work loads into a list, keep the best list found so far -- not merely the lowest value for *this* worker.